# Is current information about readout-errors of qubits on IBM quantum devices available on some internet page?

Tags: qiskit

I've used to check the readout errors on subpage of https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net, but with the new IBM Q Experience version it's no longer possible, as new composer page doesn't have this information.

I'm perfectly aware that there are scripts and tools that allows me to check it with qiskit and python (the answer is here at the time of writing https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/community/question?questionId=5cefd62c4aa56a00721856ae), but I'm interested in checking the errors via browser. I've searched through IBM QX new version but couldn't find it, though I've seen gates errors when looking up on "Your backends" panel.

What I'd ideally want is a one internet page displaying all readout errors of all qubits for all available devices. Information about single and multi-gate errors would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: To better answer the user's question, as far as I know, there is no page that can be accessed through a web browser that contains the readout-errors for each individual qubit for each device that is the most updated information.**

This question may be better suited to be in either the [IBM Q Community Forums](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/community), or possibly the [Quantum Computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/), but I will provide what answers I can.

On the main page of the new IBM Q Experience you should have a list of backend devices available to you on the right hand side of the window. If you click on on of these devices, it will open another window with a graphic that displays the Single-qubit error rate for each qubit, and the CNOT error rate for each connection.

To see the specific readout errors in a browser, you would have to go to this [device page](https://www.research.ibm.com/ibm-q/technology/devices/). However, it will only show you the average readout error across all qubits.

EDIT: To better answer the user's question, as far as I know, there is no page that can be accessed through a web browser that contains the readout-errors for each individual qubit for each device that is the most updated information.

Comment: Hello Matthew,

thank you for answer. IBM Q forum would be my first shot, but as you can see upon visiting the link you posted, I'd be closed by 11 Jun and directed users to post on stack Exchange. I did't think of QC stack -- my bad.

Back to the point, as I've stated, I've notice the panel with CNOT and single qubit gate error rates and I know there's a page for average readout error, but that's not what I'm looking for. Am I to understand that there's no internet page providing information I need? If so please state that in the answer and I'll accept it as proper one.

Comment: I added an edit to my original answer. If you are looking specifically for that information on a web browser, then unfortunately there is none that I know of. The only way I know to obtain all of that information for each individual qubit is through Qiskit, as you had mentioned earlier in your original post.